# Menu using while-loops

Tags: python, menu, while-loop

How would you implement a menu where the user has to pick the first option before continuing? I'm thinking of using a while loop where:

```
    menu= '''0 - enter number
    1 - do something with number
    2 - do something else
    3 - do something else
    4 - quit'''

    user_option = ()
    while user_option!=4:
        elif user_option==0:
            num = int(input("What is your number? "))
        elif user_option == 1: 
              do something
        elif user_option==2: 
              do something
        elif user_option==3: 
              do something
```

basically I want to figure out a way to have a way where if user picks option 1 2 or 3, then it would say "pick option zero first" and if it picks option zero first then the program would work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the lines of having it so its like while user option does not equal 0 print "pick option 0 first" and then outside the while loop is the program. I do not know much python so I cannot help with the syntax but that is how I would do it in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`cmd`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/cmd.html#module-cmd) module for this. The code should look something like this,

```
import cmd

class MyCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    """Simple command processor example."""

    def do_0(self, line):
        """enter number"""
        num = int(input("What is your number? "))

    def do_1(self, line):
        """do something with number"""

    def do_2(self, line):
        """do something else"""

    def do_EOF(self, line):
        # Return from the shell
        return True

    def postloop(self):
        print

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyCmd().cmdloop()
```

When you run it you get something like this,

```
(Cmd) help

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
0  1  2

Undocumented commands:
======================
EOF  help

(Cmd) help 0
enter number
(Cmd) help 2
do something else
(Cmd) help 1
do something with number
(Cmd) 0
What is your number? 32
(Cmd)
```

Comment: Is there a much simpler way of doing it using a nested while loop?

Comment: That'd be re-inventing the wheel. Unless you are newbie you should not build something that already exists